# Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin URL Scheme for iOs and Android

Tags: android, ios, url-scheme

I have a `Webapp` from where you can access **Facebook**, **Twitter** and **Linkedin**.

I would like that if you are accessing from a mobile device, if you have the Facebook app installed, the link should be opened in the app and not in the web browser.

I have found the `URL Scheme` in **iOS** and **FB**, **TW**

```
fb://[your path here]
twitter://[your path here]
```

but not for **Linkedin** (iOS) or any of this for **Android**.

I have google a lot but I have not found anything, and of course I have not access to the Android or iPhone apps to define the cutom `URL Scheme`...

Comment: Have you tried this `linkedin://`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the main problem is how to do in Android.. I will try yor suggestion! thx!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to check an app(facebook/twitter/linkedin) has been installed or not. If it is installed you can call url via webview instead of webbrowser from your application

Comment: That's not my goal, I would like to launch the app directly